# Should I ask if the position has been filled? How should I ask?

Tags: interviewing, communication, hiring-process, recruitment, email

I had an phone interview two weeks ago, and last week I met with them in person for a web designer position. I thought I did well because they were expressing how lucky I am that I made it this far, and they seemed to like my personality. I was told I would hear a response next week.

The day after the interview I received an email asking for a few samples of my code and I didn't need to rush, just send it in by next week. I didn't reply to to the email immediately because I didn't want to sound desperate. So I sent it in the beginning of this week.

Now it's the end of the week, and I've been feeling a bit anxious, and I'm not sure if I should email them if the position has been filled. How should I ask?

Answer (score 3):

> Now it's the end of the week, and I've been feeling a bit anxious, and
>   I'm not sure if I should email them if the position has been filled.
>   How should I ask?

Wait until the beginning of next week.

Then just call or send a casual note:

> Hi, it's 07Rhino. I haven't heard from you in about a week since I sent my code samples.
>
> Is there anything else I can get for you as you consider my
>   application for the position of X?

Don't say anything about the position being filled already. That starts to sound a bit desperate.